# How to snip same part of screen as last time?

Tags: windows-10, screenshot, snipping

In windows 10, I can use the Snipping Tool or Snip & Sketch to snip a part my screen (basically a screenshot + crop to selection). I would like to snip the same part of the screen after I perform some other operation in another application that changes what's shown in that part of the screen. I have to manually perform this operation for example by pressing some button in another application.

An example use case would be:

1. I run my code to draw something to a canvas in my browser
2. I snip that part of the screen
3. I change the code to modify what's drawn to that part of the screen
4. I'd like to capture the same rectangle from the first snip.

Is there an easy way to do this in Windows 10?

One way I can think of doing this is to screen capture that region (for example using LICEcap) then dig in to find the desired frames. This is non-ideal because my intermediate operation could take a long time, there might be quality issues with the extracted frames, and it's a lot of work to use some tool to extract frames.

### Solution Summary

Multiple solutions worked; here are brief differences (see review sites for more detailed comparisons)

[ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) and [Greenshot](https://getgreenshot.org/downloads/) are the best

- ShareX has more features

  - doesn't sacrifice too much convenience
  - probably has higher proficiency ceiling so it's preferred if you need to snip on a regular basis
- Greenshot is simpler to use out of the box

[Snagit](https://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.html) probably also fulfills my needs but I didn't try it because it costs $50 (didn't bother with the 15 day free trial).

Other methods either didn't work or would not be convenient enough.

Comment: I edited the title and added a line to hopefully clarify the question. I want to snip the same rectangular part of my screen (e.g. 10px from top, 25px from left, 100px height, 200px width - a fully specified rectangular part of my screen) after performing operations in another application (e.g. run my code that draws to canvas). Something equivalent would be to screen capture a video of that part of the screen then find all the relevant frames, but that's non-ideal.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Greenshot](https://getgreenshot.org/) has an option to `Capture last region`.  Highly recommended.

[image: example of snipping a region]

Also very easy to do quick edits such as highlighting and obfuscation:

[image: example of editing an image]

Answer (score 12):

As far as I know there is no way to "re-snip the previously snipped area" using the snipping tool.

The best way to achieve a similar functionality with the snipping tool is to the **Window Snip** or **Full-Screen Snip** available in the Mode Menu. Clicking the same window showing a different section of code etc. and trimming it down to the section you want.

Alternatively the open source tool [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) looks to have a similar functionality as you describe. The menu options for that are further described [here](https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/issues/3079) in a GitHub feature request for said functionality.

ProTip 1: The keys <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> launches the new/alternative (?) snipping tool in Windows 10 quicker.
ProTip 2: Windows 10 in 1903 now has a multi-clipboard build in, [turn it on in the settings](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-new-clipboard-windows-10-october-2018-update), and you can use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste any of the last 10 (?) copied items.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an easy way to do this in Windows 10?

Unfortunately this isn't possible using any of Windows 10's own screenshot tools.

> I am open to using 3rd party tools.

TechSmith [Snagit](https://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.html) is probably the best tool for the job for this.

> I want to snip the same rectangular part of my screen (e.g. 10px from top, 25px from left, 100px height, 200px width - a fully specified rectangular part of my screen)

The following settings would accomplish exactly that:

[image]

Using the above configuration, every time you press `Print Screen`, the same region of the screen would be captured and saved as an image file in your chosen target folder.

Answer (score 2):

One fairly straightforward way to do this is to separate the capture operation from the crop operation. Capture either the entire screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrnScr</kbd> or a window with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrnScr</kbd>; paste into an image editor which supports layers<sup>1</sup>; repeat until you have all of the captures as layers of a single image; then crop the image and save the layers out one by one.

<sup>1</sup> I use the GIMP, but I'm sure there are plenty of other options.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the Print Screen methods also posted, you could use the Window snip (from Snipping tool). Then as long as the window stays the same size you'll always keep the same section of the screen selected. Alternatively, if window changes size, you can put a larger application in the background and select that with the 'Window Snip', which will capture the screen and all windows in-front of it.

[image]

Here's an example of selecting a larger window behind the one of focus:
[image]

Comment: In this case the area I want to capture is part of a large window, and I think this method works only if the snipping region is larger than the relevant window. However if that were the case I would just snip the relevant window directly rather than a larger window behind it. So I can only imagine this would be useful if what I wanted to snip spanned more than 1 window (or if I could get an entirely transparent window on top of the snipping region).

Comment: Alt+PrintScreen captures the current window. No need to use the snipping tool

Answer (score 0):

If you size your web browser to the rough snip size and scroll to your desired capture area then you can:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd>
2. Save to file or whatever
3. Make your coding changes
4. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> in the web browser and it should remember how far you scrolled.
5. Go back to Step #1

Comment: Unfortunately areas of the browser that I don't want to snip has the GUI controls for modifying what's displayed. This would work if my desired snip area was a corner that I could scroll to the end to (but it's somewhere in the middle...)

Answer (score 0):

[Screenpresso](https://www.screenpresso.com/features/) can do that

[image: Screenpresso "previous region" feature screenshot]

It can run portably without installing and supports tons of other useful features like OCR (optical text recognition), video recording or screenshot of a scrolling window

Answer (score 0):

[PicPick](https://picpick.app/de/) lets you "***Repeat Last Capture***" among many other features.

It is also available as portable version and included in [PortableApps](https://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/picpick-portable).

For further details see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PicPick).

[image]