# Is there a Windows 10 App to launch a particular keyboard combo when icon is clicked from taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, productivity

Is there a Windows app, which I can maybe pin to my taskbar, which automatically launches a key combo when i click on that app's pinned icon?

I want to open Snip & Sketch app's snipping screen, which can be launched by a combo of Win Key + Shift + S.  [Snipping Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZV2t.jpg)

I know I can Pin the Snip & Sketch app itself, but it launches the app, from which I then have to click the snip button.  [App Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKu7N.jpg)

Is there an app, which would directly launch the combo and open the snipping screen when I click on its icon in the taskbar? I need to do a lot of snipping for a project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 Webstore apps, how do I run them in a batch file?](https://superuser.com/questions/1540101/windows-10-webstore-apps-how-do-i-run-them-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: Nope, that process just opens the Snip and Sketch Window, as can be opened by clicking the Snip and Sketch App icon. I still have to click on the snip button from that opened window. Thanks for your prompt reply, but unfortunately it seems I just have to press the 3 keys together for the time being.

Comment: why don't you just press Win+Shift+S? If you need more advanced screen snipping then you should use a 3rd party solution. There are lots of good ones like Greenshot, Screenpresso... [How to snip same part of screen as last time?](https://superuser.com/q/1490126/241386), [Screen shot with basic annotation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/42217/3579), [Free Windows program to save screenshots immediately on a key press](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/506/3579), [Take a screenshot of the scrollable area of a Windows 8 app?](https://superuser.com/q/789607/241386)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions phuclv. My issue got resolved through another comment though. If needed for my work, I will consider using specialised snipping tools like those for snipping a particular part of screen etc.

Comment: You can roll your own. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868449/send-windows-key-in-batch-script for two keystrokes or https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/06/simulates-printscreen-key-sendkeys.html for one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though there can be better options to do what you want to do, for example some 3rd party snipping softwares, but to answer this specific question, you can use the following method.
 - download and install [autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
 - create a script file, for example myscript.ahk
 - put the following code into the script file:

```
send #+s
```

- save the file, right click on the file and choose "compile script".
- myscript.exe will be created in the same folder and it does what you
  want
- pin the exe to your task bar

Comment: Thank You. This is exactly what I wanted. Solved my issue without much fuss!! Upvote not displayed because of low reputation, but You have mine. :)

Answer (score 1):

Answer already accepted, but here is a solution that doesn't need 3rd party software.

The Snipping Tool .exe takes switches, such as `/clip`.  You can save the .exe and the switch you need as a shortcut, and pin that to your start menu.

See this page for a fuller explanation: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/capture-screen-region-snippingtool-clip-shortcut-windows-10/

edit: This is for the older tool "Snipping Tool". Not tested for the new version "Snip & Sketch".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For now, my hotkey is serving the purpose! So haven't tried this method. Not a tech guy, so not so intuitive for me. I am sure some curious tech geek will verify whether this works or not. Cheers.